# Unit Test pushing to a ViewController

Tags: swift, xctest

I'm trying to run a test case that verifies that a certain trigger lead to the correct pushViewController. The app is doing everything fine, when executing this code:

```
        let testController = 
            ContributionsViewController(
                nibName: "ContributionsViewController",
                bundle: nil)
        println("currentTopVC: \(navigationController?.topViewController)")
        navigationController?.pushViewController(testController, animated: true)
        println("VC after Pushing: \(navigationController?.topViewController)")
        println("No of VC: \(navigationController?.viewControllers.count)")
```

Which I can proove by lookging at the output:

```
currentTopVC: Optional(<AppMenu.MenuViewController: 0x7fdabae62860>) 
VC after Pushing: Optional(<AppMenu.ContributionsViewController: 0x7fdabada39a0>) 
No of VC: Optional(2)
```

The original "MenuViewController" which is set in the AppDelegate is replaced by the ContributionViewController.

However, executing the same code, from a XCTest, fails.

The pushViewController is simply ignored!

Answer (score 2):

An I want to give the solution right a away:

You must not push the viewcontroller with animated:true

It has to be animated:false.

```
let testController = 
            ContributionsViewController(
                nibName: "ContributionsViewController",
                bundle: nil)
        println("currentTopVC: \(navigationController?.topViewController)")
        navigationController?.pushViewController(testController, animated: false)
        println("VC after Pushing: \(navigationController?.topViewController)")
        println("No of VC: \(navigationController?.viewControllers.count)")
```